# boto3 Error: socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a script that uploads files in a directory to s3 using the boto3 AWS SDK. I've been using it for weeks with no issue, and today it will upload a random amount of files (between 1-3 out of the 5 total) and throw the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
  conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
  for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
  socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

My code is below, I added the time.sleep(2) as a troubleshooting method to see if maybe I was making requests too quickly, but it didn't solve the issue.

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
import os
import time


def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    access_key = 'ACCESS_KEY'
    secret_key = 'SECRETS'

    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                      aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        return False


def archive_to_s3(files):
    for file in files:
        upload_to_aws('daily_data/'+file, 'bucket', '2020/'+file)
        os.remove('daily_data/'+file)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Other information:

```
Nameservers:
1.1.1.1
1.0.0.1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested below, I did a dig on the endpoint, showing 1.1.1.1 as the server, and enabled DEBUG logging on my end. When I ran the first test to get the logs, it worked flawlessly and uploaded all of the files as expected.

Comment: Try enabling verbose log and  `dig` the S3 bucket endpoint that boto3 is using. I'm pretty sure it's a DNS issue.

Comment: I enabled the verbose logging on my end and it randomly started working properly on the first test to try and get information. Wonderful.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this. I am able to make many requests to AWS services and then I suddenly receive a `socket.gaierror`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to upload to my AWS S3 bucket and it works perfectly:

```py
import boto3


BUCKET = 'myBucket'
s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))
bucket_resource = s3

bucket_resource.upload_file(Bucket = BUCKET, Filename=picture_fn, Key=picture_fn) # uploading
```

Comment: That works for one file and mine updates between 1 and 3 of them before hitting the error. As I said mine worked perfectly for weeks, until today.